# How can I set a data cap per application?

Tags: applications, data-monitoring

In Android, you can see how many data each application has used. You can also forbid an application from using data by hand. And you can set an automatic data cap for the entire system. But is there a way to **automatically cap how much a certain application can use**?

An example scenario is how Cyanogen (a custom ROM) kept trying to download Android updates from Google on 3G, over and over again, even though it couldn't do anything with them. It was of course not supposed to do that, but it did this for many users. It emptied my monthly bundle in a day. In the statistics, this data usage showed up under the Google Services Framework, if I recall correctly.

I did not want to block this application altogether, because much of the Google stuff depends on it. So I wanted it to be blocked from using any more data over a certain threshold. In the end, I disabled the receiver that queries for updates; but that was an emergency solution that shouldn't have been necessary.

I'd also like to be able to cap certain applications individually in the future, for who knows what might happen. I might want to cap my Internet radio in case I forget to turn it off, or whatever. I can't find an application that can do this; can you?

Comment: Well, I don't know of any application that can "cap" data usage, but there's a useful application called [Android Firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jtschohl.androidfirewall&hl=en) that can disable / enabled Wi-Fi and 3G/4G connection so you can use the application to disable Wi-Fi and 3G/4G connection for certain applications when these application do not need an Internet connection. You could also log a request to the developer of Android Firewall to have a capped feature in future release of this application.